# Google local search rankings is it possible without the use of citations

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-ranking, google-local-search

I have a client that is wanting a website design for his self-run business... Basically he is a self employed plumber so his home address is not visitable by the public, however the problem here is that he does not want his home address visible on the internet at all for one reason or another.

I have informed him the benefits of having his address visible for such reasons as trust by customers as well as the benefits via Google's local search algorithms (Citations - Visible Address Details) on various directories including Google Maps, and Google Places. But he is clear that he does not want his address online and wants SEO + Web Design without any citations. Now, I care about my reputation in my local area and do not like do half-cut jobs, If I do SEO I want them to be the best they can otherwise word of mouth that customer could say to someone else after my services they are no where to be seen, (I know you can't keep them all happy but none the less).

This is kinda new for me since Google introduced local rankings and something I've never had to do... So my question is fairly simple and hope that people who reply have some kind of experience in attempting ranking websites locally without citations.. Is it even possible to rank a local website with Google's local algorithms without the use of citations (address information)?

Answer (score 1):

Local SEO is not based on address alone. For starters you can for example create a webmaster account in Google Webmaster Tools and register the site as a local site that would still carry the necessary point to local SEO as the address would.

Also you should be most aware that Google and other search engines algorithms value unique content more than any other variable, so as to your question why not create a blog with unique local content related to the niche you are targeting that would do the wonders.